# Source code of original Netscape Navigator

Tags: source, browser, opensource-projects

Where is it possible to download the source code of the first *open source* browser *Netscape Navigator* released in about 1998?

I already searched for it and wasn't able to find the original version of this browser from 1998.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google `mozilla source code 1998` found [Downloading Source Archives - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Download_Mozilla_Source_Code) which lists [a URL pattern to the Mozilla FTP server](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/PROJECT/releases/RELEASE/source/). Going by that I quickly [found](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/mozilla/source) what appears to be the original release of the Mozilla source code, with file dates around Q2 1998.

Comment: I believe the genesis of netscape was mosaic, released by ncsa somewhere around 1993. [Here](http://www.ncsa.illinois.edu/Projects/mosaic.html)'s a link.

Comment: @bdowning Was the Mosaic source code ever released? Wikipedia lists it as license "Proprietary". Anyway, the OP asked about Netscape Navigator, a version of which was released as open source under the name Mozilla around that time, so I assumed that's what s/he is after.

Comment: That's why I added a comment, not an *answer*.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yes, I wanted the source code of first open source browser, I heard that it's netscape navigator, but I didn't know that it's under name mozilla.

Comment: @xralf https://github.com/alandipert/ncsa-mosaic

Comment: @xralf If you wanted the source code for the first open source browser, it would have been better to ask for that rather than including Netscape Navigator in your question. Just a suggestion for next time.

Comment: Page not found, could anybody please update to a working link?

Answer (score 4):

The Mozilla code drop can be browsed on GitHub here: https://github.com/jrmuizel/mozilla-cvs-history/tree/781c48087175615674b38b31fcc0aae17f0651b6